# Column dependent on other column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a column that will have three possible value (possibly more later) that I'm storing as an enum:

```
yes immediately
yes later
no
```

If the choice of `yes later` is made, we also need to store the *date* that the event should occur.  It seems to me that this has to be another column.

My problem with this is that the design lacks integrity.  There's nothing to prevent `date` from having a value even if the enum is not `yes later`, nor is there anything to enforce a `date` if it is.

Can this design be improved so that there is an integrity between the two columns?  Using separate tables and different column types is definitely a possibility.

Comment: mySQL lacks support for `CHECK` constraints so presumably you must resort to triggers to enforce this kind of constraint.

Comment: @onedaywhen I was looking for a possible improvement to the design that would obviate the need for external checks.

Comment: There might be, but it would helpful to know more of the rest of your design/requirements.  The given information isn't necessarily good enough for a proper decision.

Comment: @X-Zero what else do you need to know?

Comment: @tandu - well, for example, what's performing/launching the event?  Is there some job reading through this table, and you could just supply `CURRENT_DATE` for the `yes immediately` columns (and `null` for `no`)?  Also, depending on the purpose of the entire table, I might not even store `no` entries... just store the dates (or lack thereof) - heck, the current column is effectively derived information as it is (based on the date).

Comment: @X-Zero the choice is made by a user.  There are actually four options, not three, and there could be more so simply storing the date is insufficient.  What's more is that `yes immediately` indicates "immediately after the quiz," which is an arbitrary time (not just `NOW()`).  The table has other user choices about the quiz (randomize questions, use certain question types, etc.)

Comment: @tandu If it's after some event (and happens at an arbitrary time), why are you storing a timestamp?  You should be storing an interval - the type if you can, or a nullable counter if not.  Use `minutes_after_completion` (or similar) - store the count if 'later', 0 if 'immediately', or `null` if 'no'.  Drop the enum field.  Otherwise, depending on your options (and growth thereof), this _may_ be a time to use an EAV structure (much as it gags me to admit it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this by adding a subtype table (I would also prefer a lookup table over enum, even more because you want to be flexible and add more types later):

```
ChoiceType
----------            --- the lookup table
Choice      
Desciption
PRIMARY KEY(Choice)

Event
-----                 --- your table
EventId 
Choice 
... other stuff for all events
PRIMARY KEY(EventId)
FOREIGN KEY (Choice)
  REFERENCES ChoiceType(Choice)

EventYL 
-------               --- the YesLater table
EventId 
EventDate
... other stuff for YesLater events only
PRIMARY KEY(EventId)
FOREIGN KEY (EventId)
  REFERENCES Event(EventId)
```

If you want different data stored for the other choices, then you can add an `EventYI` table (for `Yes Immediate`), an `EventNO`, etc.

The only problem with this design, is that nothing prevents an event that is not `'Yes Later'` to be added in the `EventYL` table, so this should be enforced otherwise. If only MySQL had check constraints, the table could be changed into:

```
EventYL 
-------                --- YesLater version 2
EventId 
Choice
EventDate
PRIMARY KEY(EventId, Choice)
FOREIGN KEY (EventId, Choice)
  REFERENCES Event(EventId, Choice)
CHECK (Choice = 'YL')
```

Comment: This is probably way overkill for what I'll need, but it's nice to know what I'd consider to be the *Correct* solution at least

Answer (score 0):

What about a check constraint?
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp